# onclick="window.location.assign()" function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a paging using this again. Mind you that I already tried this code line on a different project and it works flawlessly, but now it refuses to do anything when I click at it. All it did was refresh the page, there's no error in the console, there's no error on the code, there's nothing else I can think of.

```html
<button class="page" onclick="window.location.assign('?PageGet=<?= $phpValue?>')">Go To</button>
```

Comment: if you inspect the button with the console tools how does the `onlick()` appear? Does it all look correct?

Comment: It appear the way I want it to look like, no error no nothing, I asked my friend to make the same thing and it works just fine

Comment: I mean does it have a valid querystring - such as `?PageGet=3` etc ?

Comment: yup `onclick="window.location.assign('?ca=&sc=&st=&p=2')"` just like this

Comment: perhaps you need to show more of the code because I recreated a link with that `onclick` function and querystring and it worked ok

Comment: I don't what else to look at, it should be as simple as 1 2 3 but apparently not, here is the whole button in the console `<button class="page" onclick="window.location.assign('?ca=&amp;sc=&amp;st=&amp;p=2')">>></button>` and, this is in the code like `<button class="page" onclick="window.location.assign('?ca=<?= $ca?>&sc=<?= $sc?>&st=<?= $st?>&p=<?= $activePage + 1?>')">>></button>` all the `$get` is from `$get = (isset($_GET['get'])) ? $_GET['get'] : "";`

Comment: probably nothing but rather than `>>` you could try `&gt;&gt;`

Comment: doesn't solve it, as expected since It's basically just changing the display

Comment: Using buttons _as_ links, is just a misuse of HTML, and it causes accessibility issues. If you need a link to _look_ like a button - then you should really rather use CSS to format it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue MUST lie elsewhere. If you consider this very basic emulation of your problem you will find that this works 100% OK

```
<?php
    $phpValue='?ca=1&sc=2&st=3&p=4';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="page" onclick="window.location.assign('?PageGet=<?= $phpValue?>')">Go To</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn' t fix it, since the problem is not in the PHP since it post it perfectly, but when I observe I found something interesting, when I just `mouse click` the button it doesn't work, it just refresh the page, but when I `Ctrl + Mouse click` it works, it actually change the page for some reason, what does that mean?

Comment: another interesting thing is, you know when you `ctrl+click` a link it's going to open a new tab, the thing is the original tab is changed to the `page 2` but the new tab is still on `page 1`